# React Native: Radio Button group with optional text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to build component from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q59Ph.png). Basically it's regular radio button component, but when the user selects button named 'Other' text input should appear where user can enter custom value.

I already have built the group, I'm just not sure how handle the TextInput part.

What is the best way to structure the component like this?

Comment: perhaps take a look at this ex https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button-group.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export const Radio = () => {
  const [isOtherSelected, setOtherIsSelected] = React.useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("0");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        value="Other"
        checked={isOtherSelected}
        onChange={setOtherIsSelected(!isOtherSelected)}
      />
      {isOtherSelected ? (
        <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Just render text input if "other option" is checked. Control value of this input in state.

Answer (score 0):

Simple minified example

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { RadioButton, Text ,TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('rent');
const [otherPayment,setOtherPayment] = React.useState('');
  return (

    <View style={{padding:15}}>
    <RadioButton.Group onValueChange={newValue => setValue(newValue)} value={value}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:"center"}}>
        <Text>Rent</Text>
        <RadioButton value="rent" />
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:"center"}}>
        <Text>Other</Text>
        <RadioButton value="other" />
      </View>

      
    </RadioButton.Group>

    {value === 'other' && <TextInput placeholder="Other Payment method" onChangeText={text=> setOtherPayment(text)}/>}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Expo snack - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/77f4e2